# Handling thrown exceptions from WebApi with BreezeJs executeQuery (Unhandled rejection reasons)

Tags: javascript, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, breeze, q

I am using Breeze.js and Q.js within my MVC app.

I currently have an action on my webApi

```
public IQueryable<Myobject> doMyAction()
```

This can do 2 things:

- Return a collection of objects (if the user is allowed)
- Throw a HTTP Exception (if the user is not allowed) (It may not be an "unauthorised" , this is just an example)

> throw new HttpResponseException(Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized, "Not Allowed"));
>   
>   This action gets called from javascript with breeze with:

```
var query = EntityQuery.from('doMyAction');

    // execute the query
    dcCore.manager.executeQuery(query)
      .then(querySucceeded)
      .fail(dcCore.queryFailed);
```

If the user is authorised and the logic is true, then I connect to my DB and return a nice list of Myobject() and everything is fine.

**However**, if I do a throw exception to say they are unauthorised, then in the console I get my 401 (Unauthorised) and the message:

> [Q] Unhandled rejection reasons (should be empty):

This happens before it hits the .fail() function.

I also tried putting a try/catch around the whole execute bit, hoping that I would catch an error, but had no luck.

I can see **why** this is happening in theory, as I am not returning something that executeQuery is expecting (In fact, im not returning at all, i'm throwing!), however,

### -actual question

how should I handle returning errors from the webApi with breeze, without doing something like extending the model?

The only thing I am yet to try is to make my web API return a type of dynamic, or generic object, but this doesn't feel like the best solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two approaches for this, the first is to simply throw an simple exception directly in your query method, i.e. something like this:

```
[HttpGet]
public IQueryable<Customer> CustomersStartingWith(string companyName) {
  if (companyName == "null") {
    throw new Exception("nulls should not be passed as 'null'");
  }
  ...
}
```

Or, if you want slightly more control over the HTTPResponse you can do the following:

```
[HttpGet]
public IQueryable<Customer> CustomersWithHttpError() {
  var responseMsg = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.NotFound);
  responseMsg.Content = new StringContent("Custom error message");
  responseMsg.ReasonPhrase = "Custom Reason";
  throw new HttpResponseException(responseMsg);
}
```

Note that for a **Save** operation as opposed to the **Query** operations described above, the best approach is to throw an **EntityErrorsException**. (see documentation), although throwing a simple exception will still work.

Hope this helps.